# Allowed memory size exhausted while exporting products

Tags: magento-1.7

I am getting below error as when i am trying to export products from **System->Import/Export->Export**

If i check using phpinfo(); then it says

**memory_limit 1024M &

max_execution_time 18000**

How to fix this?

Comment: try to export products in batches

Comment: Yes other ways are there but why this issue if memory_limit & max_execution_time are set as well.

Comment: Because you are trying to export a lot of products and you run out of memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use filters to export products. Hope this help

Go To: **System->import/export->Data flow Profiles->Add filter To export products**